WiX v4 - Replacing a single string in the Wix UI for the 'neutral' culture
When using WiX v4, I'd like to modify a couple of the default UI strings to include some more information. Specifically, I'd like to change WelcomeDlg_Title to have a version number in it. This isn't a translation (it will be the same for every culture), so I didn't specify the Culture attribute in my .wxl file (according to the docs, this applies it to the 'neutral' culture).
So here's what my Strings.wxl file looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxl">

    <String Id="WelcomeDlg_Title" Value="[ProductName] v1.2.3.4" />

</WixLocalization>

When I compile it, I see a bunch of errors like this:

So it looks like I have to redefine all the strings, just to change one? Is there a way around this?
Note, I tried setting Culture=en-us and it works fine, but I want to apply this change to all cultures.
